# KEYEVENTF_KEYUP does not work if KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY is used

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, keyevent

I try to simulate CTRL+NumENTER. I checked the code with a Keyboard Test Program (PassMark KeyboardTest) an it seems that NumENTER is pressed but not released. If i do not use KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY everything gets relesaed, but then I get the normal Return.

Here is my Code:

```
INPUT *ip = new INPUT[2];                   // set up input 1

(ip)->type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;                // set up keyboard event
(ip)->ki.wScan = 0;
(ip)->ki.time = 0;
(ip)->ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

(ip)->ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;                  // set ip[0] to CTRL
(ip)->ki.dwFlags = 0;

Sleep(100);

(ip+1)->type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;              // set up keyboard event
(ip+1)->ki.wScan = 0;
(ip+1)->ki.time = 0;
(ip+1)->ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

(ip+1)->ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;                 // set ip[1] to ENTER
(ip+1)->ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; // make ENTER to NumENTER

Sleep(100);

SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));            // send key

Sleep(100);

(ip)->ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;         // event for keyrelease     
(ip+1)->ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;       // event for keyrelease

Sleep(100);

SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));            // release keys

return 0;
```

Comment: Most apps use the scan code to distinguish between the two keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use *bitwise or* to set `dwFlags`. `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` adds a prefix  (0xE0 (224)) to `scanCode`.

```
(ip)->ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;         // event for keyrelease     
(ip+1)->ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;       // event for keyrelease
```